# How do I open multiple windows on app start?

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm building a MacOS app using Xamarin.Mac. Is it possible to have more than one window open automatically when the app starts up? I've tried a few things, including:

- Instantiating the window controller and calling ShowWindow() on it from the AppDelegate and ViewController
- Setting Visible at Launch for the second window's view controller in Xcode

I'm sure I'm missing something, but what?

Thanks!

Comment: You can open as many windows as you want. It is hard to say without more information why the window is not coming up. Where in the app delegate do you instantiate and show the window? How is the window created? Is it xib/storyboard based or pure code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instantiating the window controller from **StoryBoard** , you can show window as follow :

```
// Get new window
var storyboard = NSStoryboard.FromName ("Main", null);
var controller = storyboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier ("OtherWindow") as NSWindowController;

// Display
controller.ShowWindow(this);
```

More info refer to **[Working with multiple windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/user-interface/window#working-with-multiple-windows)** document .

Comment: That was it, thank you! I put this code into my AppDelegate's DidFinishLaunching method and set the correct identifier, and it worked. One thing I will note for anyone else reading is that "identifier" here means the Storyboard ID for the Window Controller.